# Show MapFragment in a DialogFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, supportmapfragment

I'm new with android development and i'm working on a app where i need to use google map to select event position and i need to show this map like a popup windows , i see this post :

[MapFragment in DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841016/mapfragment-in-dialogfragment)

I have the same problem listed on the post but i did not understand how to do this

her is what i did :

XML layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AddEventActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address :" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/map_button"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/map_icon" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/adress"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="280dp"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

on the click button :

```
map_butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Window window = getWindow();
            window.setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

            WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = window.getAttributes();
            wmlp.y -= 10;
            window.setAttributes(wmlp);
            gm = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            marker = gm.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Vous êtes ici").position(new LatLng(0, 0)));

        }
    });
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Please check my answer it may help you [GoogleMapFragment inside DialogFragment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37940597/1878148)